# Modulating the level of acetyl CoA

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes

> Describe what might happen if there were no mechanisms for modulating the level of acetyl CoA.

I am not sure what is meant by "modulating the level of acetyl CoA", or what mechanisms contribute to this. Presumably the citric acid cycle would be affected in some way because acetyl CoA enters it, but I'm not sure what exactly would happen.

Comment: What type of organism are we considering? Respiring or fermentating?

Comment: Probably respiring, but there is no additional detail in the question.